# Top align elements from the bottom view

Tags: react-native

I have two Views under my main View

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Image
          resizeMode="contain"
          source={require("../assets/logo-large.png")}
          style={styles.logo}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.content}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)}
          defaultValue={email}
          placeholder="Your email"
          autoCompleteType="email"
          textContentType="emailAddress"
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
```

My code for styling looks like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "gold",
  },
  content: {
    flex: 2,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
  },
});
```

What I want to achieve is to have a `header` with logo at the top of the screen and to have the `content` below, but I want to have all elements in `content` to be top aligned. At the moment those elements are `center` aligned in `content`.

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Since your main view defaults to flex-direction = column then your content style `justifyContent: "center",` will arrange elements from content at vertical middle and `alignItems: "center"` will make them horizontal center. You need to remove those to keep the content elements to start from the top.

Please update your styles to the following.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "gold",
  },
  content: {
    flex: 2,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
  },
});
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted it using `justifyContent` on `header` and `footer` styles.

```
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "gold",
    paddingBottom: "10%",
  },
  content: {
    flex: 2,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
  },
```